# Noncommutative Expand into power series

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, operators

I am new to Mathematica and am trying to apply it to quantum mechanics problems.

The practice project I am dealing with now is considering quantum harmonic oscillator and ladder operator algebra used to solve it. I had to define replacements, which would take into account all of the algebraic properties when dealing with ladder operators (linearity, commutation relation, non-commutative product, etc.), and then apply these replacements to the Hamiltonian in standard p-x form to convert it into ladder operator form.

I've encountered a bit of a snag in the final replacement, which should expand:

```
(a+b)^2 = a**a + a**b + b**a + b**b
```

where `a, b` are operators. Conventional `// Expand` does this commutatively. Is there a way to do it for a general power?

All the help is much appreciated!

Comment: Try `Block[{Times = NonCommutativeMultiply}, Replace[Expand[(a + b)^2], c_^k_. :> (Times @@ ConstantArray[c, k]), 1]]`

Comment: Hm, no, it doesn't seem to work. Naturally, the first and easiest thing I tried is just straight out define `noncomexpand := {(a_+b_)^2 -> a**a + a**b + b**a + b**b}` and applying this as a replacement works, but eventually I will be dealing with higher powers and this will not be sufficient..

Comment: "it doesn't seem to work" - a concrete example of what does not work would be very helpful in seeing what's going on, as opposed to just saying "it doesn't work".

Comment: Apologies, you are right. Certainly, your code works when evaluated simply as it is. But when I try to apply it to the the end result of a series of replacements with @@, it goes haywire. The main error message is `ReplaceRepeated` but I see no associated problems with that. Perhaps I may be using the syntax wrong. The main idea is to define the Hamiltonian, then just apply a set of replacement rules to it, so that we transform it into ladder operator form. Could you perhaps define your code as a replacement rule (such that it can be used with /. syntax)?

Comment: Can you come up with at least a small/simple example of where it fails? Also, you will note I used `Replace[]` instead of `ReplaceAll[]` (`/.`), as indiscriminate replacement can lead to hard-to-diagnose behavior.

Comment: I have an expression of the form `expression //. replacementrules @@ your code`. It is difficult to give a small example, as it seems your code conflicts with a lot of my replacementrules. And frankly there is a lot of them (hence, the output is 4 lines long). The shortest message I can share here is: `<expression> is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, \and so cannot be used for replacing`

Comment: It seems easier to just fix whatever generated `expression` so that it uses `NonCommutativeMultiply[]` instead of `Times[]`, as opposed to insisting on post-processing by replacement rules. Witness e.g. `Inner[NonCommutativeMultiply, {{a, b}, {c, d}}, {p, q}, Plus]` compared to `{{a, b}, {c, d}}.{p, q}`.

Comment: Indeed, all the rules and definitions are defined with CenterDot for this very purpose. I however, didn't figure out yet how to define noncommutative expand for arbitrary power.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [NCAlgebra](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC) package.

```
NCExpand[(a + b)^2]
(* a ** a + a ** b + b ** a + b ** b *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Block[{Power = (NonCommutativeMultiply @@ ConstantArray[##]&)}, Distribute[(a + b)^2]]
```

> a ** a + a ** b + b ** a + b ** b

Also: a variation on J.M.'s suggestion in the comments:

```
Block[{Times = NonCommutativeMultiply}, Expand[(a + b)^2] /. 
  Power -> (Times @@ ConstantArray[##] &)]
```

> a ** a + a ** b + b ** a + b ** b

Answer (score 0):

With the teaching assistants help, we were able to procure the following form for noncommutative expand, which works (when applied as a replacement):

`noncomexpand:={x_^{n_?IntegerQ} /; \[Not] ConstQ[x] && n > 0 :> CenterDot @@ ConstantArray[x, n]}`

Hope this helps!